# Where to Put Variable Equations in SQL Statement?

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, oledb

I am running some calculations using MS Access.  Below is the overall code that is giving me trouble:

```
Dim cmd3 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Criteria (Calculation, [Interval], Tier_Juncture_1, Weight) _
SELECT ?, ?, (M * 0) + B _AS Tier_Juncture_1, _
((Avg(C." & Calculation & " * G.Growth) - Avg(C." & Calculation & ") * Avg(G.Growth)) / (StDevP(C." & Calculation & ") * StDevP(G.Growth)) * 10) AS Weight _
FROM (Sum(G.Growth) / Count(*)) - (1 * (Sum(C." & Calculation & ") / Count(*))) AS B, _
(Sum(C." & Calculation & " * G.Growth) - ((Sum(C." & Calculation & ") * Sum(G.Growth)) / Count(*))) / (Sum(C." & Calculation & " * C." & Calculation & ") - ((Sum(C." & Calculation & ") * Sum(C." & Calculation & ") / Count(*)))) AS M, _
" & Calculation & " AS C INNER JOIN " & Growth_Rate & " AS G _
" & On_Statement & "", con)
    cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Calculation", Calculation)
    cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Interval]", Interval)
    cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

To be more specific, my goal is to insert the result of this formula into my table named `Criteria` in the field `Tier_Juncture_1`:

`(M * 0) + B _AS Tier_Juncture_1`

As you can see I have two variables in this equation, `M` and `B`.  Here are the formulas for each:

`(Sum(G.Growth) / Count(*)) - (1 * (Sum(C." & Calculation & ") / Count(*))) AS B`

`(Sum(C." & Calculation & " * G.Growth) - ((Sum(C." & Calculation & ") * Sum(G.Growth)) / Count(*))) / (Sum(C." & Calculation & " * C." & Calculation & ") - ((Sum(C." & Calculation & ") * Sum(C." & Calculation & ") / Count(*)))) AS M`

My question is, where in my SQL statement, do I put the formulas for my two variables sot that my original formula for `Tier_Juncture_1` can use the variables?  As you can see above, I tried to put them in my `FROM` clause but I get this error: `Syntax error in FROM clause.`

There shouldn't be any problems with the formulas of the variables themselves.  I've tested them independently and they both return the correct values without errors.  I just need to know where to place them in my SQL statement.

**UPDATE**

Per the suggestion below, I have removed the parameters from my SQL Statement.  It now looks like this:

```
Dim cmd3 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Criteria (Calculation, [Interval], Tier_Juncture_1, Weight) _
SELECT " & Calculation & ", " & Interval & ", (M * 0) + B AS Tier_Juncture_1, _
((Avg(C." & Calculation & " * G.Growth) - Avg(C." & Calculation & ") * Avg(G.Growth)) / (StDevP(C." & Calculation & ") * StDevP(G.Growth)) * 10) AS Weight _
FROM (Sum(G.Growth) / Count(*)) - (1 * (Sum(C." & Calculation & ") / Count(*))) AS B, _
(Sum(C." & Calculation & " * G.Growth) - ((Sum(C." & Calculation & ") * Sum(G.Growth)) / Count(*))) / (Sum(C." & Calculation & " * C." & Calculation & ") - ((Sum(C." & Calculation & ") * Sum(C." & Calculation & ") / Count(*)))) AS M, _
" & Calculation & " AS C INNER JOIN " & Growth_Rate & " AS G _
" & On_Statement & "", con)
    cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

But when I run this I get the following error: `Syntax error in FROM Clause.`

I believe I am getting this error because I inserted the equations for the variables `M` and `B` from my original post.  So my question still stands.  Where do I place these equations in my SQL statement.

**2nd UPDATE**

Here is the SQL statement returned by `Debug.Writeline(cmd3.CommandText)`:

`INSERT INTO Criteria (Calculation, [Interval], Tier_Juncture_1, Weight) SELECT Current_Ratio, MRQ, (M * 0) + B AS Tier_Juncture_1, ((Avg(C.Current_Ratio * G.Growth) - Avg(C.Current_Ratio) * Avg(G.Growth)) / (StDevP(C.Current_Ratio) * StDevP(G.Growth)) * 10) AS Weight FROM (Sum(G.Growth) / Count(*)) - (1 * (Sum(C.Current_Ratio) / Count(*))) AS B, (Sum(C.Current_Ratio * G.Growth) - ((Sum(C.Current_Ratio) * Sum(G.Growth)) / Count(*))) / (Sum(C.Current_Ratio * C.Current_Ratio) - ((Sum(C.Current_Ratio) * Sum(C.Current_Ratio) / Count(*)))) AS M, Current_Ratio AS C INNER JOIN Quarterly_Growth_Rates AS G ON (C.Ticker = G.Ticker) AND ((IIF(C.Period = 4, C.Year + 1, C.Year)) = G.Year) AND ((IIF(C.Period = 4, 1, C.Period + 1)) = G.Qtr)`

Comment: Your query CommandText is trying to use `SELECT ?, ?, ... FROM ...` and parameterized queries cannot do that. Parameters can only be used to specify column *values*, not column *names* or arbitrary SQL text. This might be one of those cases where you actually do need to "glue together" your SQL CommandText rather than use parameter substitution.

Comment: @GordThompson How would I "glue together" my SQL correctly?

Comment: @GordThompson Per you suggestion I've taken out the parameters.  The new code is listed in my original post.  I am getting this error now `Syntax error in FROM clause`. I believe I am getting this error because I inserted the equations for the variables `M` and `B` from my original post.  So my question still stands.  Where do I place these equations in my SQL statement.

Answer (score 1):

In order to return non-aggregate fields and aggregate functions in your SQL, IE `Avg(G.Growth)`, you must suply a `GROUP BY`.

By looking at your code, I know that `Calculation` is not an aggregate because you use the same variable for the field and the table name.

If you need further help, you need to supply the resulting SQL for inspection, we dont know what is in your variables. IE, `Debug.Writeline(cmd3.CommandText)`

Comment: I've edited my original post.  I posted the wrong code before.  That is the correct code and I am getting this error `Syntax Error in FROM Clause.`  I believe I am getting this error because I inserted the equations for the variables `M` and `B` from my original post.  So my question still stands.  Where do I place these equations in my SQL statement.

Comment: I also added the full SQL resulting from `Debug.Writeline(cmd3.CommandText)`

Comment: Your `from` clause is all messed up. You have `[Some Calculation] AS B, [Some Calculation] AS M, [Some Calculation] AS C INNER JOIN ...`  What are you trying to do here? This isn't proper SQL.

Comment: I need the values from `[Some Calculation] AS B` and `[Some Calculation] AS M` in order to calculate `(M * 0) + B AS Tier_Juncture_1` which needs to be inserted into my table.

Comment: I would suggest your get this working in an Access Query, then replace the parts you need to in VB.  This is the best way to learn.  Everything in your FROM must be in a table format. I think Access allows nested tables so you should be able to do something like this: `(SELECT [Some Calculation] AS B, [Some Calculation] AS M, [Some Calculation] AS C) as TmpTable INNER JOIN ...`

Comment: `[Some Calculation] AS B` and `[Some Calculation] AS M` are aggregate functions and are not in table format.  They do not relate to `[Some Calculation] AS C`  How will that work?

Comment: We have moved a long way from the original question.  I suggest if you cannot get the SQL working, you post another question asking for help on the SQL.